# Smoothing GPS data?

Tags: gps, smoothing

I am working with a GPS track that is 7 days, and shows me trips by travel mode. Occasionally a "stationary" point will pop up amongst a set of "vehicle" points, I want to smooth this data to delete these random points, and also to create a polyline for each trip taken by each mode.

Can anyone suggest ways to do this please?

The end goal is the generate summary stats, but need the data to be clean first.

Comment: What are the specific characteristics of the points you’d like to omit? Why are they ‘random’? Please click ‘edit’ and modify this question to include some examples and more of your thinking about the way the data look.